# How can I add a hypertext link on elements of a Handlebars template?

Tags: cordova, templates, handlebars.js

I am new to handlebars templating and I hope that what I am trying to do is achievable.
I want to put a link on each of the listed text elements in the table of the following handlebars template. The link should show a new page containing the clicked element. I am working on a cordova project. Any idea?

```
<script id="myinterests-tpl" type="text/template">
    <header class="bar bar-nav">
     <button class="btn pull-right btn-primary" id="menumescibtn">
      menu
     </button>
     <h1 class="title"><font color="#FFFFFF">My interests</font></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="bar bar-standard bar-header-secondary">
        <font color="#FF0000"><div id="errcon"></div></font>
        <font color="#FF0000"><div id="errchoix"></div></font>
        <table>
        {{#cinterets}}
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="ci{{cinteretid}}" value="{{cinteretid}}">
        {{cinterettxt}}
        <!-- I want to put a link on each of the above text which should show another page containing cinterettxt only-->
        </td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>
        {{/cinterets}}
        </table>
    </div> 
    <div class="bar bar-standard bar-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-positive btn-block" id="validcibtn">VALIDATE</button>
    </div>
 </script>
```

**here is the json data that is passed to the above template**

{"cinterets":[{"cinterettxt":"agriculture","cinteretid":"5"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 21","cinteretid":"21"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 22","cinteretid":"22"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 23","cinteretid":"23"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 24","cinteretid":"24"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 25","cinteretid":"25"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 26","cinteretid":"26"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 27","cinteretid":"27"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 28","cinteretid":"28"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 29","cinteretid":"29"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 30","cinteretid":"30"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 31","cinteretid":"31"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 32","cinteretid":"32"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 33","cinteretid":"33"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 34","cinteretid":"34"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 35","cinteretid":"35"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 36","cinteretid":"36"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 37","cinteretid":"37"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 38","cinteretid":"38"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 39","cinteretid":"39"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 40","cinteretid":"40"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 41","cinteretid":"41"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 42","cinteretid":"42"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 43","cinteretid":"43"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 44","cinteretid":"44"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 45","cinteretid":"45"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 46","cinteretid":"46"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 47","cinteretid":"47"},{"cinterettxt":"centre interet 48","cinteretid":"48"},{"cinterettxt":"evenementiel","cinteretid":"6"},{"cinterettxt":"immobilier","cinteretid":"1"},{"cinterettxt":"locations","cinteretid":"2"},{"cinterettxt":"sport","cinteretid":"4"},{"cinterettxt":"ventes","cinteretid":"3"}],"mesci":[{"cinterettxt":"evenementiel","cinteretid":"6"}]}

Comment: What data are you passing to your compiled template method?

Answer (score 0):

How you will write your link element is up to you. The way you should be iterating your "cinterets" data in your Handlebars template is as follows:

```
{{#each cinterets}}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ci{{cinteretid}}" value="{{cinteretid}}" />
            {{cinterettxt}}
        </td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: @PaulNgom: So what's the problem, then?

Comment: i want to have a link  like <a href="newpage"> {{cinterettxt}}</a> that will take me to a new screen containing  {{cinterettxt}}. I am in a cordova project. I tried putting the link like that but i do not know where to put newpage. Will it be a template or an html page. If the latter, where will i save it?

Comment: Handlebars' only job is to process your template and return to you a string representation of your template with the variables substituted in. Creating new pages is a completely unrelated task.

Comment: How do i go about it?

Comment: I don't know. Your question should have a "cordova" tag.

Comment: I have changed the tags.